# SelectPdf HtmlToImage throwing "Conversion error: Unknown error"

Tags: c#, pdf, selectpdf

I am using SelectPDF to generate pdfs from a cshtml template. My PDF generates locally, but when on production I get an error.

Stack trace: 
at SelectPdf.HtmlToImage.?(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, ?[]& A_3, ?& A_4)\r\n   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.?(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)\r\n   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(String htmlString)\r\n   at Test.GenerateSelectPDF(ReportObj report)\r\n     at Test.ReportsController.d__6.MoveNext()

I've ensured that the dll, Select.Pdf.dll and Select.Html.dep are in my bin folder along with Select.Pdf.xml and Select.Tools.dep.

Since I can generate the same report locally I think this is a configuration issue.

Comment: The version of SelectPDF is v17.3.0, using .net 4 assemblies

Comment: I have changed my template files to generate a single div with the word 'test', so I am now sure that the html being generated is not the problem.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm getting a very similar error, but it's intermittent and driving me insane.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this exact problem as well, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I never did find a solution and started using wkhtmltopdf instead.

Comment: I got same issue when I added WebPageFixedSize but started working again when I removed it

Answer (score 1):

Check the execution by increasing the MaxPageLoadTime property of the converter (HTMLToPDF object)

By default, the value is 60 seconds

Example:

```
converter.Options.MaxPageLoadTime = 240;
```

Reference: [Link](https://selectpdf.com/docs/P_SelectPdf_HtmlToImage_MaxPageLoadTime.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar issue: **System.Exception: Conversion failure error 5**.

Regarding the documentation - Select.Html.dep missed execute permissions. I've added execute permissions for IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool (change user if your app is not running under default pool) and that resolved the problem.